# Is there a way to delete branch automatically after a pull request is merged on Github?

Tags: git, github

We usually delete the branch that has been worked on after it has been merged after a pull request - is there a way we can set this to happen by default so it automatically deletes the branch once a PR is approved and merged?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is available in **GitHub**, there are open requests for this function to happen:

- https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1121
- https://github.com/Mergifyio/mergify-engine/issues/68

In **BitBucket** however, there is this feature called "Close branch after Pull Request merge", [see the docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/merge-a-pull-request-945541513.html)

However - *regardless of deleting the branch in the remote repository*, you and your fellow developers would still need to delete the local branches tracking the (deleted) remote branch. You can do this (for all branches) by running:

```
$ git remote prune [--dry-run] origin
```

Above command removes local branches that are stale (usually - there's no upstream branch  on the remote any more). Use it with caution after reading the [Git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote-empruneem).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. [Since August 2019 only](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-07-31-automatically-delete-head-branches-of-pull-requests/).

As announced on Twitter [here](https://twitter.com/GHchangelog/status/1156532447456219136) and [here](https://twitter.com/harrymarr/status/1156776737818206208) by **Harry Marr**, co-founder of [Dependabot](https://twitter.com/dependabot), which is [now part of Github](https://twitter.com/harrymarr/status/1131472831743705088):

> You know how you merge a pull request then sit there a few seconds for it to do its thing, then click to delete the branch… well… you don’t have to do that any more!

See "[Managing the automatic deletion of branches](https://help.github.com/en/articles/managing-the-automatic-deletion-of-branches)"

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/repository/automatically-delete-branches.png]

A `git remote prune origin`, as mentioned in [Kleskowy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2240141/kleskowy)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52328917/6309), is still needed locally though.